# JsonParseException at the time of json-deserialization, Excpected Object but found

Tags: java, collections, gson, json-deserialization

I want to get javabean from json string. javabean contains one map having key as a one javabean and value as javabean. But I am getting following error on line
TestBean testBean2 = gson.fromJson(json, new TestBean().getClass());

I am using google gson.
please help me to resolve this.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<ProductBean, OfferBean> duplicateOfferMap = new HashMap<ProductBean, OfferBean>(0);
        ProductBean productBean = new ProductBean();
        OfferBean offerBean = new OfferBean();
        duplicateOfferMap.put(productBean, offerBean);

        TestBean testBean1 = new TestBean();
        testBean1.setDuplicateOfferMap(duplicateOfferMap);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting ().disableHtmlEscaping ().create ();
        String json = gson.toJson(testBean1, new TestBean().getClass());

        TestBean testBean2 = gson.fromJson(json, new TestBean().getClass());
    }
}

public class TestBean
{
    private Map<ProductBean, OfferBean> duplicateOfferMap = new HashMap<ProductBean, OfferBean>(0);

    public Map<ProductBean, OfferBean> getDuplicateOfferMap() {
        return duplicateOfferMap;
    }

    public void setDuplicateOfferMap(Map<ProductBean, OfferBean> duplicateOfferMap) {
        this.duplicateOfferMap = duplicateOfferMap;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String json = gson.toJson(testBean1, TestBean.class);
```

or so

```
Type myType= new TypeToken<MyBean>() {}.getType();
```

and then

```
String json = gson.toJson(testBean1, myType);
```